# Meaning of 对拆 (對拆) in 套路 names

Tags: characters, cantonese

There are different sequences of movements in martial arts (套路 - forms) all having their names. Some of these names are quite clear but some are hard to understand for me. For example a double hand form is called:

```
工字伏虎拳對拆 (工字伏虎拳对拆)
```

This form name comes from 洪家拳 system which is well-known in southern China  (Guangdong province). So the names of forms are in Cantonese dialect.

The part of the name 伏虎拳 is clear for me but I can't find anywhere the meaning of 對拆. It should mean something like 'sparring set' or 'versus' but only 對 (对) can mean 'versus'.  Is 對拆 some kind of a regional Cantonese word? Also, an additional question: how could 工字 be translated (if it can)?

Also I wonder: can I write/say 對拆套路 by analogy to 武器套路 or 拳術套路 (拳术套路)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote:- "...can I write/say 對拆套路"

套路 means a set, (or in Japanese, "Kata"), of martial arts movements strung together in a continuous sequence for solo practice.

對拆 means a "breakdown" or a separation / dismantling of the constituent offensive / defensive parts of 套路 for practice with a partner or a demonstration of them by the teacher.

Therefore, no, it would be incorrect to write/say 對拆套路 if by 對拆套路 you mean 對拆 is practiced as or like a 套路.  It would be a contradiction in terms.

對拆 also cannot be used as an adjective of 套路 because the two terms, as used in martial arts, are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Here 拆 means 拆解，dismantle something into basic component, so as to understand and apply it to handle complex combination.

Answer (score -1):

**bkrs**：**对折** 
1) 对半的折扣。（一半的折扣） fifty per cent discount; 50％ discount; reduced by one half:
照货价对折 allow a fifty per cent discount off the price; reduce the price by one half
2) 对半摺叠。to **fold in two** 。print.folio
freq. rank #60050
**linguee**:sell at a 50% discount
不常见: fold in two  folio e.g. 以书中第 6 对折页（ 图 16）为例 as seen in folio 6v (image 16),
 also note example in TV show 今日说法
http://tv.cctv.com/2019/04/08/VIDEVF1V14RsBWtaIkbNuEzg190408.shtml?spm=C52056131267.PkHCdznQvTLi.0.0  ）；０：１５：有去无回的外出 ０：１８：普通的案件的话 ０：１９：police officer: **车牌不会对折**
bkrs: **工字** in the shape of character 工，工字形(梁)断面 I-beam

**对拆**："对拆"什么意思!? https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/140590125.html 合起来就是说，俩人相互（演练自己的招数并）拆解对方的招数（，从而找出对方的破绽，用来修补破绽），现在的话讲就是找BUG。

Comment: OP is asking about 對拆 not 對折.

Comment: The second part of this answer makes 对拆 clear enough for me, although it would've been better if you'd translated the answer. My Chinese is not as good and I had to use google :-) Thank you for clarifying 工字 - now I'm surprised that I didn't understand it (there's for example 十字路口).